# How to edit a JPEG data on iOS without re-compressing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, jpeg

Say, I have got an image from the user's album, and now I want to modify metadata or MCUs in file, then save it back as a new photo or re-write the original. In other words, I have to to edit the JPEG data blocks in lossless mode.

I grab the image with the following default code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
      [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      selectedImage.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change metadata with the [library iphone-exif](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) without new compression of your JPEG image.

**Update 1:**
You might also look at [libjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg), especially at jpegtran (a utility for lossless transcoding between different JPEG formats.)

As far as i know you cannot change MCUs (MCU size!) without new compression.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! But is there no way to somehow prepare the JPEG data in memory, then edit and save it?

Comment: With iphone-exif you can edit metadata of a JPEG representation in memory (`NSData * uiJpeg =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation (anImage, 1.0 );`)

Comment: Well then it's all clear for me concerning metadata. But you also state that there is no way to access and modify macroblocks. Is it because of the API limitation and sandboxing? Is there such a data abstraction close to JPEG MCUs, which I can study?

Comment: I don't think there's an API to modify JPEGs at the level you specify--you probably want to load your JPEG as raw bytes and manipulate that, perhaps with the help of a third-party (C) library.

Comment: You still need a way to get at the JPEG data after you get it from the picker. Not sure this will work, but you could try looking at `CGDataProviderCopyData( CGImageCGImageGetDataProvider( [image CGImage] ))`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of this helped. I have been looking everywhere, and it looks like API is always decompressing JPEG files before passing them to an app.